# Handling tone dial for cell phones

Tags: telephony

For example I call on the specific phone number and automaticly connect to some kind of server(?) which is able to handle all my actions while I'm connected. I want to try myself in coding this server, but I have no idea how to start =)  Please give me some links to read about this or maybe some keywords to google it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Actionscript3 will handle either web applications or desktop applications. Since you're talking about using a cellphone , I doubt you can achieve what you're looking for with AS3.

You could consider a web application whereas a user would connect to the internet via her phone and interact with your application but as far as calling a number and get some form of server response, you may have to look at using another language than AS3.

Comment: Of course I understand this, thanks. AS3 will be used for the client side applicaton. So the question is what language\technology to use for creating a server. I think it some kinde of phone menus (push 1 to talk with operator etc.) Tag AS3 wath my mistake, excuse me!